# NodeXL- Nodes with No Edges

Tags: excel, data-visualization, network-analysis

I'm making a network visualization with NodeXL. My graph includes several nodes that have no edges but that I would still like to display- but it doesn't appear that these nodes show up when I show the graph. Does anyone know how to include these 'isolated' nodes in the visualization?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem as well and have not found a "built-in" solution that exists inside NodeXL.  One (poor) solution is, when you import or add your edges to NodeXL, add one additional row to your edgelist for each isolated node you wish to appear, with the two values (2,2) for example, if you wish to force NodeXL to show unconnected node 2 in your network graph.  This node WILL appear in your network image, albeit with a circular "loop" from that node to itself.